# Multi columns breaks when I put img

Tags: html, css

I have 5 multi-columns that have scroll eventlistener. The problem is when I put pictures inside a column the others columns goes under that one. I tried some clearfix solution but does not work.

Can you help me please?

Here is a jsfiddle without pictures - I put the CSS beside (I want it to works like that but with pictures, not with text) - https://jsfiddle.net/u849yzn3/15/

And here is what happens when I put picture - https://jsfiddle.net/georgeSohan/7puf3z9m/4/

Here is the html

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix">

    <div class="scroll-class columnScroll clearfix" id="scroll">

    <div class="imgWrap clearfix"><img src="images/0-i6"> </div>
        <div class="imgWrap clearfix"><img src="images/0-i6.jpg"</div>
        <div class="imgWrap clearfix"><img src="images/0portrait.jpg"</div>


    </div>



    <div class="columnScroll clearfix"><p> Some Text</p></div>
    <div class="columnScroll clearfix"><p> Some text</p></div>
    <div class="columnScroll clearfix"><p> Some text</p></div>
    <div class="columnScroll clearfix"><p> Some text</p></div>

</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see an issue when I add images?: https://jsfiddle.net/yL4orp7x/

Comment: Ah I see it in your second example, you've pasted images randomly and broken all your HTML nesting. Start over and paste them in carefully then you'll be fine.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Ah! Not the fact that does not apears it is the problem ( this is because i did not know how to put images in fiddle to see it) but the fac that when I put in the column images the others go under that one. Make sens? If increase the preview window you will see. I try to make something like this http://weareeli.dk/ but I stuck here

Comment: How would you like the images to appear? It makes sense that if there is not enough horizontal width in the container then the next image will start on the next line.

Comment: I want to appear like here weareeli.dk . The container has width 20% because are 5 containers

Comment: That's what happens already... https://jsfiddle.net/tp9g6zec/

Comment: I cant understand how iti works now. And you did nothing to css... Maybe is because I wanted to put the img in a div? I'm just.... wow... I stuck here a few hour trying to find a solution and boom

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa thanks a lot man! I dont know what happen, but now it is work how I want.